# Programmatically Change Windows Laptop's Refresh Rate

Tags: windows, winapi, settings

I'm thinking of coding something up that will change a laptop's refresh rate based on whether or not the device is plugged in.

From my research, these are two links I came across. One is 20 years old and the other is from Microsoft, but I don't see any mentions of refresh rate specifically.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/558/Changing-your-monitor-s-refresh-rate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Does anyone have any insight into how to do this? I'm not too particular about what language would have to be used for it, so let me know whatever would be most viable. Of course I'd also have to be able to check a change in state for plugged in/unplugged, but I haven't gotten to that point yet.

I'm mostly targeting Windows 10 since that's what my device is on.

Comment: Refresh rate is **dmDisplayFrequency** in the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: What problem do you hope to solve? LCDs commonly have a fixed refresh rate that cannot be changed.

Comment: My laptop has a 144Hz display. However, it can be changed to 60Hz. When it's plugged in, I want the smoothness and performance of 144Hz. When it's unplugged, I want the ~1 hour extra battery life of 60Hz. I can do this manually in the display settings, but I forget this all the time when I'm focused on something and would write some code to do it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`EnumDisplaySettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to enumerate the information of the current display device, and then set the display by [`ChangeDisplaySettingsA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If you want to modify the refresh rate, you only need to modify the `dmDisplayFrequency` parameter of [`DEVMODEA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea).

Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    DEVMODE dm;
    ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);
    if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
    {
        cout << "DisplayFrequency before setting = " << dm.dmDisplayFrequency << endl;
        dm.dmDisplayFrequency = 60; //set the DisplayFrequency
        LONG ret = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, &dm, NULL, 0, NULL); 
        std::cout << "ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returned " << ret << '\n';
        if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
        {
            cout << "DisplayFrequency after setting = " << dm.dmDisplayFrequency << endl;
        }
        switch (ret) 
        {
        case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
            std::cout << "display successfully changed\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
            std::cout << "The settings change was unsuccessful because the system is DualView capable\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS: 
            std::cout << "An invalid set of flags was passed in.\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE: 
            std::cout << "The graphics mode is not supported.\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM: 
            std::cout << "An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include an invalid flag or combination of flags.\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED: 
            std::cout << "The display driver failed the specified graphics mode.\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED: 
            std::cout << "Unable to write settings to the registry.\n"; 
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
            std::cout << "The computer must be restarted for the graphics mode to work.\n";
            break;
        }
    } 
    system("pause");
}
```

This example is not always successful. Whether you can modify the refresh rate depends on whether your monitor supports it. This is the output of successful setup:

[image]

Comment: Damn, thank you so much! What a great answer! I'm mostly looking to do this for my personal machine. My laptop supports changing between 144 Hz and 60 Hz, and I want to have it change automatically based on whether or not it's plugged in rather than having to manually go through the settings since I pretty much always forget to do it when I unplug. But I don't want to just leave it at 60 permanently because, well, I paid for 144 Hz and I like to take advantage of the higher rate on the occasion I game on the laptop.